# Issue with Files used in Lightning Email Templates

Tags: files, lightning-email-template, content-assets

I'm having an issue with Lightning Email Templates in two sandboxes.

**Development sandbox**

1. Add image to Files.  In the files list, the file does not have the
   [Asset File] tag next to it.
2. Create a Lightning Email Template.
   Select the image for use in the Body (not using the builder).  In the Files list, the image
   file has the [Asset File] tag next to it.
3. Email sent using the template includes the image.

**Staging sandbox**

1. Add image to Files.  In the files list, the file does not have the [Asset File] tag next to it.
2. Create a Lightning Email Template.  Select the image for use in the Body (not using the builder).  In the Files list, the image file has the [Asset File] tag next to it.
3. Email sent using the template does not include the image.

For some reason, Files used in Lightning Email Templates in my Dev sandbox are automatically converted to Asset Files.  This does not happen in my Staging sandbox.

When images don't come through in the email, they have this URL:

https://someorg--devsand--c.documentforce.com/file-asset-public/abstractcamerawithlens4513ld?oid=111111

When images do come through in the email, they have this URL:

https://someorg--stagesand--c.documentforce.com/file-asset-public/Banner2?oid=2222222

If I use builder in my **Staging** sandbox to create the body, the images do appear in the email.  They never appear when I add them to the template's Body directly.

I'm stumped on why my **Development** sandbox isn't having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you ever find the solution to this?

I'm experiencing a similar issue right now where files uploaded to a Lightning Email Template (not created via the builder) in my sandboxes become asset files and hence come through when actually sending out an email using the template.

When following the exact same procedure in my **production** environment though, the files don't become asset files and hence don't come through when sending an email using the template.

I feel like I've compared all the settings etc. in the different orgs but just can't discover what causes this difference in behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), & be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You can contribute in other ways to earn enough rep (50) so that you can comment; or you could possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) & in it you can link to this Q for reference (just click "Share" at the bottom left of the post to get a URL).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/184792)